# I'm getting header info for a file that doesn't exist?

Tags: ios, http-headers, nsurlconnection, nshttpurlresponse

I'm using code that I got from a tutorial for finding the "Date Modified" info of a file on a server.  It goes as follows...

```
// create a HTTP request to get the file information from the web server
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:remoteFileURL];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"HEAD"];

NSHTTPURLResponse* response;
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];

// get the last modified info from the HTTP header
NSString* httpLastModified = nil;
if ([response respondsToSelector:@selector(allHeaderFields)]) {
    httpLastModified = [[response allHeaderFields] objectForKey:@"Last-Modified"];
}
```

And, for the most part, it works!  Wa-hoo.

Except, for a few files, it seems to be returning outdated information.  In fact, for at least one, it's returning a date (`Fri, 24 Apr 2015 04:32:55 GMT`) for a file that *doesn't even exist anymore*.  I deleted it from the server, but it's still returning that value every time I run my app, as if the file still existed.

I've checked and re-checked that the `remoteFileURL` is pointing to the right URL, and I've confirmed that the file doesn't exist on the server anymore.  And, like I said, for most files it works perfectly, so obviously the system isn't entirely broken.

This is my first experience with `NSMutableURLRequest` and `NSHTTPURLResponse` and getting file headers and such.  Is there something I don't know, that would explain this?  Could there be a cache or something that needs to be cleared?

And ideally, what can I do to ensure that the proper info is being received by my app?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try it by removing cache information ?, Add this [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];

Comment: @Jageen I knew it was a caching thing!!!  I was just expecting it to be a server-side solution.  Yeah, I added that line at the very beginning, and it works great.  Anyway, thanks for helping out the NSURL new guy.  :)  Add that as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Posting my comment as an answer**

This type of thing happends because of caching mechanism of NSURL.
Try to add below line to remove all cached data.

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
```

---

If you want to ignore caching for particulate request try below code

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:aStrFinalURL];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
```